# Call image src using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a image inside a div. Below is the current div structure.

```
<div id="imgHolder">
   <img class="smallthumb" src="imgHolder.png">
</div>
```

How can I call the image using jquery and get the same output as above?

I tried this:

```
$('#imgHolder').attr("src", "profile.png");
```

but then the final output is:

```
<div id="imgHolder" class="smallthumb" src="imgHolder.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imgHolder` is the ID of the `div` element so `#imgHolder` will refer to the `div` element that is why the `src` is getting added to the `div` element.

You need to find the image inside the div so you can use a descendant selector along with the id selector like

```
$('#imgHolder img').attr("src", "profile.png");
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#imgHolder img').attr("src", "//placehold.it/64X64&text=profile");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgHolder">
  <img class="smallthumb" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=holder">
</div>
<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: How can I get this to work if `$('#imgHolder)` was created dynamically?

Comment: @Bekki what do you mean by created dynamically... If you run this after the element is created it will work

Comment: Thanks. for some reason `<img class="smallthumb" src="imgHolder.png">` does not get added. In my code `$('#imgHolder)` is created dynamically - could this be the reason?

Comment: @Bekki https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lyszpzkf/1/ - the `img` element is not there then add it

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the `img` to change the attribute of `img`.

```
$('#imgHolder img').attr("src", "profile.png");
```

As `img` is the direct child of div, you can also use the children `>` selector

```
$('#imgHolder>img').attr("src", "profile.png");
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#imgHolder > img').attr('src', 'profile.png');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgHolder">
  <img class="smallthumb" src="imgHolder.png">
</div>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to add image dynamically:

```
$('#imgHolder').html('<img src="http://img42.com/kzCbY+" />');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uq886k7e/1/)

Comment: Thanks. for some reason `<img class="smallthumb" src="imgHolder.png">` does not get added. `$('#imgHolder)`  is created ynamicallly - could this be the reason?

Comment: @Bekki Can you add complete code in question, how the image is being added

Comment: @Bekki Because there is no `img` inside the `div`. To add one see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uq886k7e/1/)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. So why didn't `$('#imgHolder img').attr("src", "profile.png");` work? Will it work If I had `<div id="imgHolder">  <img class="smallthumb"></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find any descendants like so :

```
$('#imgHolder').find('img').attr("src", "profile.png");
```